# Data binding to dictionary with Tuple key in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, data-binding, tuples

I have a `Dictionary<Tuple<SomeEnum, double, string>, double>` that I'm trying to bind to in Xamarin. I'm just trying to bind the value (the double) to a label, nothing terribly fancy. The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out the path syntax to bind to a Tuple key. I know that with a `Dictionary<string, double>` I would just let `Path="[" + keyString + "]"`, for example, but I can't figure out what to do if I want to use a Tuple as the key. Even [Microsoft's page on data binding path syntax in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't seem to explicitly handle this case, although it does note that

> Inside indexers you can have multiple indexer parameters separated by commas (,). The type of each parameter can be specified with parentheses. For example, you can have `Path="[(sys:Int32)42,(sys:Int32)24]"`, where sys is mapped to the System namespace.

Now, I'd assume that this holds for single indexer objects too. So in my dictionary case, I suppose I would have something like `Path="[(sys:Tuple<SomeEnum, sys:double, sys:string>)???]"`, but I'm not sure what goes where `???` is. And I'm not sure if I'd need a namespace before `SomeEnum`. And finally, I can't seem to find any more detailed documentation. So I'll take help on any of these fronts.

Ultimately, I fear I may have to just give up, switch to a `Dictionary<string, double>`, and let the string be the `.ToString()` concatenation of the types in the Tuple, e.g. by letting each key be `string key = SomeEnum.SomeValue + "," + someDouble + "," + someString`, but I'd really just prefer to do this correctly. I'm open to changing the Tuple to another non-string type if that helps though. Perhaps some other immutable type? I'm not terribly proficient with C# data binding beyond the basics, so any help or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43209056/880990

Comment: Thanks Olivier, but that is for the new C#7 ValueTuple type. I am using the old C#6 Tuple type, which is bindable. See e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386940(v=vs.110).aspx. So I'm not sure if the question you posted can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, multi-indexer is supported by data-binding. The syntax is the following:

> ```
> <object Path="[index1,index2...]" .../>  
> or  
> <object Path="propertyName[index,index2...]" .../>
> ```
>
> -- [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, creating a `Tuple` within a XAML path can be quite difficult. There is 2 solutions to this:

1. Create a custom markup extension to generate the `Tuple`
2. Create a dictionary that support multi-indexer

The easiest and cleanest is probably solution#2. (`PathToDictionary[{ns:Tuple a,b,c}]` vs `PathToDictionary[a,b,c]`).

---

Use this as the dictionary:

```
public class TripleKeyedDictionary<TKey1, TKey2, TKey3, TValue> : Dictionary<Tuple<TKey1, TKey2, TKey3>, TValue>
{
    public TValue this [TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2, TKey3 key3]
    {
        get { return this[Tuple.Create(key1, key2, key3)]; }
        set { this[Tuple.Create(key1, key2, key3)] = value; }
    }
}
```

Example of usage: `PathToDictionary[Banana,b,c]`

Full example for LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new
    {
        Lookup = new TripleKeyedDictionary<Fruit, string, string, string>
        {
            { Tuple.Create(Fruit.Banana, "b", "c"), "value" }
        }
    };

    var binding = new Binding("Lookup[Banana,b,c]");
    binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    binding.Source = data;
    binding.FallbackValue = "fallback";
    binding.TargetNullValue = "null";

    var block = new TextBlock().Dump();
    block.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public enum Fruit
{
    Apple, Banana, Cactus
}
public class TripleKeyedDictionary<TKey1, TKey2, TKey3, TValue> : Dictionary<Tuple<TKey1, TKey2, TKey3>, TValue>
{
    public TValue this [TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2, TKey3 key3]
    {
        get { return this[Tuple.Create(key1, key2, key3)]; }
        set { this[Tuple.Create(key1, key2, key3)] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very elegant alternate solution. Thanks!