# how to bind a list of tuple in a listbox?

Tags: wpf

I have a listbox like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="list1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyListWithTuples}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding value1}" />
                                    <Label Content="{Binding value2}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

In my view model I have this collection:

```
private ObservableCollection<(decimal value1, decimal value2)> _myCollection= new ObservableCollection<(decimal value1, decimal value2)>();
        public ObservableCollection<(decimal vaule1, decimal value2)> MyCollection
        {
            get { return _myCollection; }
            set
            {
                _myCollection= value;
                base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("MyCollection");
            }
        }
```

But the data isn't show. However if I convert the tuple to a dictionary, I can bind to Key and Value properties and the data is shown. But I would like to avoid to convert the tuple into a dictionary.

Are there some way to bind the listbox to a list of tuples?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to bind to a ValueTuple field in WPF with C#7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208852/is-it-possible-to-bind-to-a-valuetuple-field-in-wpf-with-c7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike the [Tuple Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.tuple?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), the new [C# tuple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) only define fields, but no properties. So you can't use them with WPF data binding.

However, with

```
public ObservableCollection<Tuple<decimal, decimal>> MyCollection { get; }
```

you could use this XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding Item1}" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Item2}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```