# How to fill a ComboBox with indexes of bound collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I want to create a `ComboBox` with contents of `TextBlock`s that are in the from "Sample 01", where the number is replaced with the index of the item (from 1).

Below is roughly my current code:

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="ComboSampleItems"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Height="20"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ReportModel.SampleData}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSampleScans}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ????, StringFormat=Something here?}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I am using `INPC` to ensure that changes on the VM reflect the View, as I am using MVVM.
How can I achieve my desired result? I have considered converters, but am not sure it fits in what I am wanting to do, or if there is a better way.

Does this at all relate to [this topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections do not provide an *explicit* index for their items. In other words, although e.g. a `List<string>` contains strings and all of them can be indexed, there is no *property* for the index of an individual item. What you could do is simply expose a collection of (Index, Item) tuples. Note, I use `Tuple<string, int>` here, because value tuples like `(string, int)` [are not bindable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208852/is-it-possible-to-bind-to-a-valuetuple-field-in-wpf-with-c7). You could also construct a custom type or use [`KeyValuePair<string, int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=net-6.0) instead.

```
public List<Tuple<string, int>> IndexedSampleData { get; }
```

You can initialize it using LINQ and its `Select` method. Depending on your concrete case, you might as well use a `IEnumerable<(string, int)>` or an `ObservableCollection<(string, int)>` for this purpose.

```
IndexedSampleData = SampleData.Select((item, index) => new Tuple<string, int>(item, index)).ToList();
```

In XAML you can use  a [`MultiBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.multibinding?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) in combination with [`StringFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), see [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings). Refer to the tuple components using the properties `Item1` and `Item2`.

```
<ComboBox
   x:Name="ComboSampleItems"
   Grid.Column="0"
   Height="20"
   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
   ItemsSource="{Binding IndexedSampleData}">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
               <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1:D2}">
                  <Binding Path="Item1"/>
                  <Binding Path="Item2"/>
               </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

[image: ComboBox with sample data.]